Using Python 'subprocess' to open and close programs
Opening external programs with either subprocess or os works fine. However, using terminate() or kill() to close them only works sometimes. E.g. I can open and close the Notepad application and I'm trying to do the same with Firefox, it opens but doesn't terminate. I'm using Windows 10.
With Notepad I used:
> import subprocess
> a = subprocess.Popen('notepad')
> a.terminate()

It works in this case. But doing the same with other programs like Firefox:
> b = subprocess.Popen('C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe')
> b.terminate()

opens Firefox, but then just stays open. I did the same with kill() and also tried with os.popen() but the same thing happens, it opens and doesn't close.
What is the difference with Notepad and Firefox? I guess Notepad is a Windows built-in and Firefox is not, so how can you make it work with other applications like Firefox?

terminate signals to the process, but the application decides how to respond. but kill will do it unconditionally!. did you try os.kill(b.pid, signal.SIGKILL) and test it with other signals?

@GhorbanM.Tavakoly not on Windows. On Windows the Win32 API function TerminateProcess() is called to stop the subprocess. kill() is simply an alias for terminate().

I have mostly used Python for mathematical purposes and this kind of programming is new to me, I don't really understand what a "signal" is. Anyhow I tried with subprocess and it couldn't close it either, but I found a way that works with selenium.

also noted that subprocess which can close Notepad in Win10, doesn't close it in Win11.

I think this happened because of terminate() call terminates only target processes, not child processes - they will simply become orphaned. But this behavior explained in docs for multiprocessing, not for subprocess:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.terminate
So, I'm not sure about subprocess module, but I expect same behavior there.
As I remember there is not processes hierarchy in Windows, so this call terminates only target process, which already spawned other and they are still working after terminate() call.
